# How can I find out if a curve is orthogonal using differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, curves, orthogonality, differential

How can I find out that the curves included in the $y=c(2x+c)$ are orthogonal when $c$ is a random constant?
I've tried defining $c$ with $x$ and $y$ but I failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Strawberry: The envelope is a zero radius circle at the origin. Please feel free to roll back if it was not a typo. Please mention the Clairaut's form ode $y=2cx+c^2$  has a solution as a set of tangents as context.

Comment: One line has slope $2c$ and another has slope $2c'$. How will these possibly be orthogonal unless $4cc'=-1$? (And please rewrite your title.)